# What does the notation $|\text{grad} \ F|$ mean?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, notation, boundary-conditions

I am currently studying the textbook *Principles of Optics: Electromagnetic Theory of Propagation, Interference and Diffraction of Light*, 7th edition, by Max Born and Emil Wolf. Page 5, chapter **1.1.3 Boundary conditions at a surface of discontinuity**, says the following as a note at the bottom of the page:

> $^*$ For later purposes we note a representation of the surface charge density and the surface current density in terms of the Dirac delta function (see Appendix IV). If the equation of the surface of discontinuity is $F(x, y, z) = 0$, then
> $$\rho = \hat{\rho} \mid \text{grad} \ F \mid \delta(F) \tag{17a}$$
> $$\mathbf{j} = \hat{\mathbf{j}} \mid \text{grad} \ F \mid \delta(F) \tag{18a}$$
> These relations can immediately be verified by substituting from (17a) and (18a) into (17) and (18) and using the relation $dF = |\text{grad} \ F| dh$ and the shifting property of the delta function.

Can someone please explain to me what this notation with $|\text{grad} \ F|$ means? I have never encountered it before.

Thank you.

Comment: $grad F$ is a vector (the gradient of F) and |grad F| is the magnitude of that vector.

Comment: @planetmaker Oh, so 17a just means $\hat{\rho}$ times the magnitude of $\text{grad} \ F$ times $\delta(F)$?

Comment: To add to @planetmaker's comment, an alternative notation would be $|\vec{\nabla} F|$

Comment: @BySymmetry Ok, thanks. The form that (17a) and (18a) are written in almost makes it look like some new notation, rather than the magnitude.

Comment: It looks totally normal and is very common notation.Only nit-pick is that I'd expect the magnitude bars closer to it's vector and not evenly spaced between the constituents of the equation. $\rho = \hat{\rho}   |grad{F}|   \delta(F)$

Comment: @planetmaker I just studied bra-ket notation $\langle \mid \rangle$, so maybe that is why my brain thought it was something else.

Comment: What do the hats mean? For example what is $\hat\rho$?

Comment: @G.Smith  $\hat{\rho}$ is surface charge density and $\hat{\mathbf{j}}$ is surface current density. As mentioned in the comment by Jerrold Franklin to planetmaker's answer, this textbook was written before hats were used to denote unit vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the magnitude of the gradient of $F$.

$\operatorname{grad} F$ or $\nabla F$ denotes the gradient of the field F and thus $|\operatorname{grad} F|$ is the magnitude of the gradient of F.

It's common practise, but just a matter of taste, to use $\operatorname{grad} F$ over $\nabla F$ in order to guide the eye easier as to what is being done or used (similar to $\operatorname{curl} A = \nabla \times A$).

Comment: B & W Is a wonderful book that was written before the notation of using $\nabla$ for 'grad' was adopted.

Comment: Let me know when you get to $rot$.

Comment: @JerroldFranklin rot and curl is the same...

Answer (score 0):

If F is any scalar function ,then Grad F will be the vector one as gradient operator is a vectorial operator. In the said equation,you have a vector quantity in the left hand side.It means your right hand side must represent a vector quantity.A unit vector is there in the right hand side,so all other parts should be scalar.That's why magnitude of Grad F is taken there.It just represent a number(scalar).